# Custom data attribute for grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`grouped_collection_select` accepts nine parameters, including an options attribute. How do you add a custom attribute in options, a data tag, to be used when an option is selected?

The select is coded as of now as:

```
= f.grouped_collection_select :course_id, Discipline.order(:name), :courses, :name, :id, :display
```

I want to add a custom data attribute so that the output is like:

```
<select id="enrollment_course_id" name="enrollment[course_id]">
    <option selected="selected" value="7" data-duration=8>Introduction to Guitar (8 weeks)</option>
    <option value="8" data-duration=8>Strings 1-3 (8 weeks)</option>
    <option value="9" data-duration=10>Strings 4-6 (10 weeks)</option>
    <option value="10" data-duration=12>Basic Chords (12 weeks)</option>
</select>
```

How do we generate the custom attribute programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no nice and properly documented way to do this.

**Solution 1.** use non fully documented features of grouped_collection_select:

```
f.grouped_collection_select :course_id, Discipline.order(:name), :courses_with_duration_data, :name, ->(el){el.first.id}, ->(el){el.first.display}
```

Where you need to implement `courses_with_duration_data` like this:

```
class Discipline
  has_many :courses
  def courses_with_duration_data
    courses.map {|course| [course,{data: {duration: course.duration}}]}
  end
end
```

It relies on that if you pass array of arrays to [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) the hash within the arrays will be treated as html options.

It has a disadvantage of putting view related methods to your model. And it something that might break with future rails releases as this use is not documented on grouped_collection_select, so you're probably better of generating the options yourself.

**Solution 2.** Reimplement options yourself:

Reimplement custom `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` in a helper. This could look something like this:

```
def options_for_disciple_with_courses(disciplines)
  disciplines.map do |discipline|
    option_tags = options_for_select(
      discipline.courses.map {|course| [course.display, course.id, {data: {duration: course.duration}}]}
    )
    content_tag(:optgroup, option_tags, label: discipline.name)
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

And your view would became:

```
f.select :course_id, options_for_disciple_with_courses(Discipline.order(:name))
```